# CA1051 rule violation not detected in some files

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I've added editor config to our project and the CA violations are being caught, but in some files CA1051 violation is not showing any error I have even added this in .editorconfig: `dotnet_diagnostic.CA1051.severity = error` Has anyone faced this strange behavior before? Any idea how I can make it work reliably for all files? This is present in csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Do you have a [mre]? Can you please post it somewhere (like github)?

Comment: You are talking about you don't get it as error in Visual Studio sometimes? Or maybe when building via MSBuild for example (something that is not considered "editor"?